How to set an image placeholder for Lottie animation (Swift)?
I’m trying to set an image placeholder for a Lottie animation when it cannot be loaded.
Animation.loadedFrom(url: url, closure: { [weak self] animation in
        if let animation = animation {
            self?.animateView.animation = animation
            self?.animateView.loopMode = .loop
            self?.animateView.play()
        } else {
            self?.animateView.imageProvider = Asset.placeholder.image as! any AnimationImageProvider
            self?.animateView.loopMode = .loop
            self?.animateView.play()
        }
    }, animationCache: nil)

When I run the simulator, it caches the animation. How can I fix or improve this case?
